# How do I switch to another audio output sink in XFCE?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, xfce

From the command line I can easily create another pulseaudio sink and switch to that but I have not found a way how to do this using a GUI from the Xfce desktop.

In GNOME I use **gnome-volume-control** from audio settings to switch to another audio output sink.

Is there anything similar in Xfce?

Comment: are you using pulseaudio? - is `pavucontrol` the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Pavucontrol would do it but it installs such a lot of dependencies. I was wondering if there was something more XFCE inherent (or lean).

Comment: ... ummm... but I thought xfce4-mixer also had a similar capability - but I'm depending on my ageing memory ... :)

Comment: It looks like it has but it does not show my bluetooth headset or my newly created pulseaudio sink. Feels like it's oriented more to ALSA than to pulseaudio. I may well only just don't know how to operate it (memory mumified by age).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing Xfce panel version 4.12.2: the volume indicator already has that feature. It is a pulseaudio  plugin (`xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin`) for the Xfce panel.

[image]

The output device is listed under the main scroll given more than one sink is available; on mouse hover a list of available output devices is displayed.

[image]

So, no external application is needed for the purpose discussed here, although `pavucontrol` may be useful (especially given that Xfce has no specific audio settings like other desktops have).

---

Non-Xfce-specific tools can be also used like `pasystray`(PulseAudio System Tray), as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153248/925128), similar to Sound Switcher Indicator, already mentioned under this question; `pasystray`doesn't need a new PPA to be added.

Answer (score 31):

After installing [**pavucontrol**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pavucontrol) you have graphical access to several useful settings for pulseaudio including a choice for your output device. Choose the default output device in the *Output Device* tab:

[image]

A currently playing stream of a given application can also be moved to another device in the *Playback* tab from the dropdown menu next to *Playback Stream on*:

[image]

Comment: I did exactly that but didn't get my bluetooth headphone to work unfortunately. It works perfectly in Unity though. Any idea of what might be the problem?

Comment: This worked for me using I3 (instead of Unity) on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: "Set as fallback" will not affect the already playing applications, but only those started after this change. Also, disconnecting and reconnecting a device (e.g a bluetooth speaker) will reset this setting back to the internal/wired output. Setting an output device per application under the *Playback* tab overrides the "Set as fallback" setting.

Answer (score 8):

The pavucontrol answer is correct. However I encountered difficulties to use is out of the box. I had to type the following before using pavucontrol to use my bt headphone:

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=btheadset
```

You can control if this was successful by typing:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

Output should look similar to:

> 0       alsa_output.pci-0000_03_04.0.iec958-stereo      module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
>
> 2       alsa_output.btheadset   module-alsa-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       IDLE

I also have a short script to move sound from alsa/pulseaudio to bt that I called 'toBt.sh':

```
#!/bin/bash

OCHANNEL=`pactl list modules short | grep btheadset | cut -f 1`
for i in $OCHANNEL; do
        echo "altes module $i"
        pactl unload-module $i
done
CHANNEL=`pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=btheadset`
echo "neues module $CHANNEL"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "No bt connection"
        exit -1
fi
SINK=`pactl list sinks short | grep btheadset | cut -f 1`
INPUTS=`pactl list sink-inputs short | cut -f 1`
for i in $INPUTS; do
        echo "Verschiebe in $i nach $SINK"
        pactl move-sink-input $i $SINK
done
```

To return to alsa/pulseaudio sound I've got 'toAlsa.sh':

```
#!/bin/bash

SINK=`pactl list sinks short | grep alsa-card | cut -f 1`
INPUTS=`pactl list sink-inputs short | cut -f 1`
for i in $INPUTS; do
        echo "Verschiebe in $i nach $SINK"
        pactl move-sink-input $i $SINK
done
```

Answer (score 5):

[Sound Switcher Indicator](https://yktoo.com/en/software/indicator-sound-switcher)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yktooo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound-switcher
```

[image]

While `pavucontrol` provides more differentiated options (default/fallback device versus per-application device), this tool simply changes all the above to one device, but provides easier access. Its unilateral setting can be refined in `pavucontrol` if necessary.

Answer (score -2):

I am on Xubuntu and i also faced this problem. I installed pulseaudio's manager and it works fine!

HTH

Comment: "The two utilities PulseAudio Manager and PulseAudio Device Chooser are obsolete and should not be used" ([from PulseAudio Wiki](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/PerfectSetup))