# Why does bluetooth connect but not transmit any audio?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, input-devices, headset

It connects, but then I don't get any audio in Pulse Audio or in Steam's mic settings. I don't understand why this is so hard. I can get it to work on my PS3 or mac with no trouble. I have a plantronics 2xx and Ubuntu 12.10. What can I do?

Comment: Did you go through this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headset? Note that microphone is not enabled in A2DP (high fidelity) profile.

Comment: yes I did follow those procedures, I am using default audio pairing. I tried blueman also, and it did not work and then I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is documented at [this pulseaudio launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/508522).

If you believe that this is affecting you, please login to launchpad and vote on the bug.  This helps developers prioritize the things on which they are working.

#### In the meantime

You can set the device up as a 'Telephony' device, which will give you *horrible* sound quality, but gives you the ability to use the microphone's input.