# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fails pair bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth

So I've been looking for this on google obviosly without a working solution for my problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04,terminal says that `command not found: blueman` but I found bluetooth manager in applications and so on.
I've tried also "Setup new device" from the BT option in the Ubuntu menu bar.

So I'm asking if someone knows a fix for the bluetooth not connecting to your headset issue, I'm running the latest Ubuntu LTS, obviou
sly I know how to google, otherwise I wouldn't be asking here.
Headset name is BTH20, and never had problems with it on my mac.

**EDIT:**
Output from `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` per request

```
lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:0273 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.219427] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.298419] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-9b] only partially covers this bridge
[    2.633946] usb 1-3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    3.449432] input: Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:05AC:8290.0001/input/input6
[    3.567685] hid-generic 0003:05AC:8290.0001: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[    3.567770] input: Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:05AC:8290.0002/input/input7
[    3.567834] hid-generic 0003:05AC:8290.0002: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
[   11.206026] facetimehd 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware, size: 1392kb
[   11.268170] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   11.268184] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.268187] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.268189] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.268196] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.281138] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102 build 0683
[   11.282570] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: product 05ac:8290
[   11.298055] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20703A1 Generic USB UHE Apple 20Mhz fcbga_X87
[   11.367851] facetimehd 0000:02:00.0: Firmware requested heap size: 3072kb
[   11.462761] facetimehd 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for facetimehd/1871_01XX.dat failed with error -2
[   11.641225] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[   11.919390] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.919391] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.919393] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   12.163488] brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[   15.212522] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.212527] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.212530] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[17428.856657] leds luxafor9:blue:led5: Setting an LED's brightness failed (-38)
[17428.856891] leds luxafor9:blue:led4: Setting an LED's brightness failed (-38)
[17428.857063] leds luxafor9:blue:led3: Setting an LED's brightness failed (-38)
[17428.857736] leds luxafor9:blue:led2: Setting an LED's brightness failed (-38)
[17428.857973] leds luxafor9:blue:led1: Setting an LED's brightness failed (-38)
[17428.858190] leds luxafor9:blue:led0: Setting an LED's brightness failed (-38)
[17436.790893] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[17437.332539] brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[17437.475453] facetimehd 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware, size: 1392kb
[17437.633878] facetimehd 0000:02:00.0: Firmware requested heap size: 3072kb
[17437.729069] facetimehd 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for facetimehd/1871_01XX.dat failed with error -2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to my Bluetooth headset?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headset)

Comment: Does bluetooth work? Can it connect to any device?

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/893821/edit) the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I had the exact same problem. If you look at the error messages, it seems like there is no file called `brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt`.
All you need to do is create that file manually by running the following command:

```
sudo touch brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt
```

in the directory `/lib/firmware/brcm/` and the edit it by writing random letters (it doesn't matter what you write). This fools the software and bluetooth works perfectly after doing this.
More on this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1693521

Comment: Cool, I'll try this if get the error in the future. Not using Ubuntu right now.

Answer (score 0):

According to manual for the BTH20:

> *Press and hold ON/OFF button for 5 seconds to start paring mode*

The LED should then flash red/blue.

Only then we can start to [set up a new device in our Bluetooth settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headset) using the default password (`0000`).