# Ubuntu 16.10 on DELL XPS 13 9360 - (how) to pair bluetooth headphones

Tags: bluetooth, dell, xps

On my XPS 13, I am baffled on how to pair my QC35s.  They appear in the list, but when trying to pair Ubuntu just says "Failed to pair".  No logs in /var/log/syslog and I'm stumped.

Thanks for the help

Comment: From Manual: *Slide the power switch to the Bluetooth symbol and hold until you hear “Ready to pair” or the Bluetooth indicator blinks blue* - then try to pair. If it fails remove device and try again. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headset

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve the issue is with Ubuntu. The headphones pair fine with my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not solve the problem.  It relies on bluez, so if it is not of any value, please tell me, and I'll remove the answer.

Launch bluetoothctl

```
$ bluetoothctl
```

Setup bluetooth

```
> agent on
> default-agent
> power on
> discoverable on
> pairable on
```

Setup scanning (at this point, turn on your headset and setup it up to be discoverable)

```
> scan on
```

Wait about 30 seconds or so, and type

```
> devices
```

Make a note of the MAC address of your headphones.

Copy the MAC address of your headphones, and type

```
> pair <MAC Address>
```

If it says at the bottom of the output "Pairing Successful", type

```
> trust <MAC Address>
```

And finally

```
> connect <MAC Address>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It says connection successful on the laptop, but then it's not detected as a sound device.  The headphones also don't pick up that it's paired.

Comment: but I'm way closer than before

Comment: Now you need to setup the audio sink. That's a bit beyond me I'm afraid. It's got more to do with pulse audio and bluez. Good luck though. :)