# How to undo the deletion of a bluetooth device on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS?

Tags: bluetooth

I accidentally removed my Bluetooth device (Powerbeats Pro) from the Bluetooth device list on Ubuntu.

Before the removal, I was able to pair with the device without any problems.
Is there any way I can make the device appear again?

Comment: The same way you added it the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your device is in discoverable mode. In your [case:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209544#:%7E:text=or%20other%20device.-,Place%20the%20Powerbeats%20Pro%20earbuds%20in%20the%20case.,Android%20device%20or%20other%20device.)

1. Place the Powerbeats Pro earbuds in the case. Leave the case lid
   open.
2. Press and hold the system button until the LED flashes.

Then follow the classic pairing [steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headset). You should be able to pair it again.

Comment: Yes, somehow it worked today. I was trying the same set of steps yesterday, but it wasn't working.