# bluetooth not working on ubuntu 20.04 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, bluetooth, headset

I have a Windows-installed Dell Inspiron 5502 and installed Ubuntu 20.04. Bluetooth is not working at all, since it does not show that it detects any devices. I'm trying to pair my Philips headphone—this does not work: [How do I connect to my Bluetooth headset?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headsethones).

Where should I be looking at to solve this?

Comment: Disable Fast Startup in Windows then boot Ubuntu and try again.