# Share an audio playback stream through a live audio (video) conversation like Skype

Tags: pulseaudio

In conversations using Skype, I often want to share sound output (e.g. of a Youtube video) with other people I am talking with.

So I am looking for a way to route the output to the recording input (So that the other members hear the sound output), **but I can still hear the output myself**. Furthermore I want still be able to speak with them while sharing the sound output with them.

How would I do that? I would be very thankful!

Part of my question has been answered here: [How to Pass/Record audio output as an input device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171287/how-to-pass-record-audio-output-as-an-input-device) (but it only allows for setting the output stream as input, without overlapping the real microphone)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Check id's

   ```
   $ pactl list short sources
   0   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
   2   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   3   combined.monitor    module-combine-sink.c   s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED

   $ pactl list short sinks
   0   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
   1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
   2   combined    module-combine-sink.c   s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
   ```
2. Make 2 virtual sinks, (`Virtual1` mic+music, `Virtual2` music)

   ```
   pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual1 sink_properties=device.description=Virtual1
   pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual2 sink_properties=device.description=Virtual2
   ```
3. Loopback mic to `Virtual1`

   ```
   pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 sink=Virtual1
   ```
4. Loopback `Virtual2.monitor` to `Virtual1`

   ```
   pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 sink=Virtual1 source=Virtual2.monitor
   ```
5. Loopback `Virtual2.monitor` to Analog Stereo (In my case)

   ```
   pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 sink=1 source=Virtual2.monitor
   ```
6. Then open `pavucontrol`:

   - Input Device: set fallback to `Virtual1.monitor` or using CLI:

     ```
     pactl set-default-source Virtual1.monitor
     ```
   - Output Devices: set default to Analog Stereo (In my case) or using CLI:

     ```
     pactl set-default-sink 1
     ```
   - Recording: confirm Skype from `Virtual1.monitor` or using CLI (I remove some lines from results, `avconv` as example):

     ```
     $ pactl list short clients
     23  protocol-native.c   chromium-browser
     24  protocol-native.c   chromium-browser
     45  protocol-native.c   pavucontrol
     237 protocol-native.c   avconv
     239 protocol-native.c   pactl

     $ pactl list short source-outputs
     35  0   45  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
     36  1   45  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
     37  2   45  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
     38  3   45  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
     39  4   45  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
     41  0   45  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
     42  1   45  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
     52  1   45  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
     54  1   237 protocol-native.c   s16le 2ch 48000Hz

     $ pactl move-source-output 54 Virtual1.monitor
     ```
   - Playback: set music player to `Virtual2` (2nd null device), and confirm Skype in Analog Stereo. or through CLI (`chromium` as example, see previous `pactl list short clients`):

     ```
     $ pactl list short sink-inputs
     17  3   24  protocol-native.c   s16le 2ch 44100Hz
     58  0   -   module-combine-sink.c   s16le 2ch 44009Hz
     59  1   -   module-combine-sink.c   s16le 2ch 44100Hz

     $ pactl move-sink-input 17 Virtual2
     ```

Simple Diagram (`/`,`\` loopbacks from left to right):

```
            Microphone      ---
                               \                   
            Virtual1.mon    ------  Virtual1    >   Skype
                               /  
    VLC   > Virtual2.mon    ------  Virtual2
                               \
    Skype > AnalogSt.mon    ------  AnalogSt    >   Headset
```

To switch back (normal use), see [Pulseaudio loopback unload audio output devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355082/pulseaudio-loopback-unload-audio-output-devices)

- Check module id:

  ```
  pactl list short modules
  ```
- Unload single module (or one by one)

  ```
  pactl unload-module id
  ```
- Or (reload with default modules):

  ```
  pulseaudio -k
  ```

**Notes:**

- I have use sink `id` (Eg: 1) but if you want make a script it's better to use names. (I avoided that here because they are long).
- [How do I switch to another audio output sink in XFCE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107277/how-do-i-switch-to-another-audio-output-sink-in-xfce) contains nice script to get stream `id` from name to be used with `move-sink-input` and `move-source-output`.
- I have used `latency_msec=1` which may lead to high CPU usage. In audio conversation, you may not care about delay between music and microphone. You can remove it or increase it. But for recording mix, You may look for very small delay between music & microphone.

  As I have tested it, the delay is near half to one second.
- I think some times its hard to figure out what going on like with Jack tools. It will be clear with graphic map:

[image]

Comment: Big thanks for the answer. But I am having issues: First of all in pavucontrol it only says "Monitor of Null Output".
Secondly, people I am chatting with, complain about hearing their own echo. Could I blacklist the output of skype for the sound redirection?

Comment: Sneetsher: I am not sure what you mean, I have done so. But it redirects all sound output, as initially desired, but now I want to exclude skype output from redirection.

Comment: Ok, sorry I miss that, I have updated the answer, now it shows sink names as description in pavucontrol. `pulseaudio -k` to reset all change and start over. it should be easy now

Comment: I think you made a mistake in step 3: the command should look like `pactl load-module module-loopback source=2 latency_msec=1 sink=Virtual1`, because actually you did not loopback the mic ...

Comment: By default it loopback the microhpone, but you can test it works.`pactl load-module module-loopback source=2 latency_msec=1 sink=1` , you should hear mic in headset. then `pactl unload-module 30` (30 is the id showed when you load-module.

Comment: Sneetsher: does not work in my case.
Do you know how I could redirect a specific output stream, say only from chromium?

Comment: Sneetsher: In other words: What I want is to loopback a client (pactl list short clients). When chromium-browser for example is listed there.

Comment: Sneethser: Sorry to be unclear: Thank you everything works, as you instructed, but How could I replace the steps in pavucontrol with command line?

Comment: Sneetsher: Thank you so much!!! One last question: is the high cpu usage of pulseaudio during loopback normal?

Comment: Sneetsher: Could you look at the following script: http://pastebin.com/gUdtua8A. Bascially I created a script that is triggered when clicking an icon on my desktop, if I want to route output. It should prepare everything needed for me and undo everthing as soon as I close pavucontrol. Unfortunately, when closing pavucontrol, I can hear myself all the time (microphone is somehow connected to the audio output.). Only reboot helps. Could you help me?

Comment: Sneethsher: Nevermind, I added `pactl unload-module module-loopback`