# Recording phone calls in Ubuntu 20.04 - not just Skype

Tags: sound, microphone, phone, speakers, audio-recording

What is a good piece of software for recording calls? I am not just talking about Skype but Facebook calls, Google Hangouts, Meet, everything.

I have been using Simple Screen Recorder but that only records their side of the conversation. Kazaam does the same, it only records their side. I can never get Audacity to do it either, there are too many channel combination settings [upwards of 60 on my machine].

Is there a simple software package which records both sides of the conversation?

Comment: This sounds like a job for Jack, which you can use to redirect audio.

Comment: Probably the easiest is to load **module-loopback** run `pactl load-module module-loopback` in the terminal **once** after that your microphone will be routed to your speakers and you if you record your speakers, while reviving calls, your voice and the caller's voice will be both recorded. to unload it run `pactl unload-module module-loopback`
`

Comment: With that, you can run `pavucontrol` and then start recording with audacity for example and choose **monitor...** in the recording tab in **pavucontrol**

Answer (score 11):

## Record directly

#### From command-line with `ffmpeg`

- You can record and merge **both desktop and microphone** audio with `ffmpeg` like so:

  ```
  ffmpeg -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor -i <(arecord -f CD) -filter_complex amix -acodec libmp3lame "$(date +%d_%m_%y__%H_%M_%S)".mp3
  ```

  **Change** `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor` to your **.monitor** device as it appears after running this command:

  ```
  pacmd list-sources | grep ".monitor"
  ```

  Which will output something like this:

  ```
  name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor>
  monitor_of: 0
      device.class = "monitor"
  ```

  Your device is the one after `name:` without `<` and `>`.

  **Alternatively, you can have your *.monitor* device automatically detected like so:**

  ```
  ffmpeg -f pulse -i "$(awk '$2~/.monitor$/ {print $2; exit;}' <(pactl list short sources))" -i <(arecord -f CD) -filter_complex amix -acodec libmp3lame "$(date +%d_%m_%y__%H_%M_%S)".mp3
  ```

  Your recording will be saved in the same directory you run the command from and will look like `20_02_21__21_27_21.mp3` with start date and time in the file name like `Day_Month_Year__Hour_Minute_Second.mp3`.

#### From GUI with OBS Studio

**OBS Studio** is a free and open source software that allows for capturing multiple streams at once and provides:

> High performance real time video/audio capturing and mixing. Create
> scenes made up of multiple sources including window captures, images,
> text, browser windows, webcams, capture cards and more.

**OBS Studio** supports [installation on Ubuntu](https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#linux) and has extensive [help and documentation](https://obsproject.com/help). Guides and tutorials are also abundantly available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZL0rqcNxsO0).

**OBS Studio** is also available for install from snap like so:

```
sudo snap install obs-studio
```

#### From GUI with vokoscreenNG

**[vokoscreenNG](https://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html)** is an easy to use screencast creator to record educational videos, live recordings of browser, installation, videoconferences, etc.

**vokoscreenNG** is available for install from snap like so:

```
sudo snap install vokoscreen-ng
```

---

## Route and mix

#### With simplicity

1. Play your **microphone** through your **speakers** like so:

   ```
   aplay <(arecord -f cd)
   ```
2. Record your **speakers or desktop** audio with your favorite **audio or screen** recorder or with **command-line** **from a second terminal** like so:

   ```
   parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor --file-format=wav "$(date +%d_%m_%y__%H_%M_%S)".wav
   ```

   Or to reduce file size, use it with an encoder that is installed on your system ... **`lame`** for example, like so:

   ```
   lame -r -V0 <(parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor) "$(date +%d_%m_%y__%H_%M_%S)".mp3
   ```

   **Change** `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor` to your **.monitor** device as it appears after running this command:

   ```
   pacmd list-sources | grep ".monitor"
   ```

   Which will output something like this:

   ```
   name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor>
   monitor_of: 0
       device.class = "monitor"
   ```

   Your device is the one after `name:` without `<` and `>`.

   **Alternatively, you can have your *.monitor* device automatically detected like so:**

   ```
   parec -d "$(awk '$2~/.monitor$/ {print $2; exit;}' <(pactl list short sources))" --file-format=wav "$(date +%d_%m_%y__%H_%M_%S)".wav
   ```

   **and so:**

   ```
   lame -r -V0 <(parec -d "$(awk '$2~/.monitor$/ {print $2; exit;}' <(pactl list short sources))") "$(date +%d_%m_%y__%H_%M_%S)".mp3
   ```

   Your recording will be saved in the same directory you run the command from and will look like `20_02_21__21_27_21.wav` with start date and time in the file name like `Day_Month_Year__Hour_Minute_Second.wav`.

#### With PulseAudio

1. Load pulseaudio's **module-loopback** like so:

   ```
   pactl load-module module-loopback
   ```
2. Run **pavucontrol** like so:

   ```
   pavucontrol
   ```
3. Start recording with your favorite application like **audacity** for example.
4. In **pavucontrol's** UI and under **recording** tab select *Capture from* **[ Monitor ... ]** next to your recording application like so:

   [image: screenshot]

#### With JACK Audio Connection Kit

1. Install **JACK** and required additions like so:

   ```
   sudo apt install qjackctl pulseaudio-module-jack
   ```
2. Choose **NO** when you see this:

   [image]
3. Run JACK UI **qjackctl** from **applications** or from terminal like so:

   ```
   qjackctl
   ```
4. Start JACK by clicking on the **start button** like so:

   [image]
5. Reload **pulseaudio** like so:

   ```
   pulseaudio -k
   ```
6. In **JACK UI**, click the **Connect button** and have your devices connected like so:

   [image]
7. Run **Audacity** and select **Edit -> Preferences -> Devices** and configure it like this:

   [image]
8. **Start recording with Audacity**.

---

## Notice

- You can install **ffmpeg** like so:

  ```
  sudo apt install ffmpeg
  ```
- You can install **lame MP3 encoding library** like so:

  ```
  sudo apt install lame
  ```
- You can unload **module-loopback** like so:

  ```
  pactl unload-module module-loopback
  ```
- You can install **pavucontrol** like so:

  ```
  sudo apt install pavucontrol
  ```
- After starting or stopping **JACK** reload **pulseaudio** like so:

  ```
  pulseaudio -k
  ```
- **For usability ease**, you can save a command that works for you, for example this:

  ```
  ffmpeg -f pulse -i "$(awk '$2~/.monitor$/ {print $2; exit;}' <(pactl list short sources))" -i <(arecord -f CD) -filter_complex amix -acodec libmp3lame "$(date +%d_%m_%y__%H_%M_%S)".mp3
  ```

  in a file in your *home directory*, name the file `record.sh` and make it executable like so:

  ```
  chmod +x ~/record.sh
  ```

  then, you can add an alias like this:

  ```
  alias record='bash ~/record.sh'
  ```

  to your `~/.bashrc` file so you can afterwords run the short command:
  `

  ```
  record
  ```

  from any directory and get the same result. You first need to close and reopen the terminal again to pick up changes to `~/.bashrc` for this to work.
- Here is extra information about [arecord and aplay](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/aplay.1.html), [parec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pacat.1.html), [pacmd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pacmd.1.html), [lame](https://lame.sourceforge.io/), [ffmpeg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/ffmpeg.1.html), [module-loopback](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-loopback), [pavucontrol](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pavucontrol.1.html), [pactl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pactl.1.html) and [What is JACK](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/What%20is%20JACK).

Comment: Thank you for this - I tried the OBS Studio approach but it created a BIG save files, even if I turn the video recording res right down. e.g. for a 15 sec conversation it created a 4MB file. For an entire conversation the file size would be huge. I tried the loopback module approach with Audacity, but the large amount of inputs to choose from was a hindrance to getting both sides to record easily. I am slowly coming to the realisation that there is no good way to do this in Linux without creating a large save file, so for a one hour interview I'd be looking at something like a 1GB file size...

Comment: ... however, this can then be imported to Audacity and exported as an mp3 and reduced to about 50MB. It's not a great procedure but it'll probably have to do.

Comment: @C26 That is too big a size if what you need is only audio. You can do with **0.1** that size or even **less** for the same duration if you tweak the [OBS Settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U042cwRU8E)

Comment: @C26 Audacity has an option called [Software playthrough](http://www.jeanphilippepernin.net/ressources/3.%20traitement%20des%20medias/4.%20traitement%20du%20son/documents/manual/man/recording_preferences.html) which routs the mic to the speakers similar to PulseAudio's module-loopback. I am not sure about the quality of this one though. Worth noting nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

It is quiet easy and quick with one command using a multimedia pipeline like GStream or FFmpeg/LibAV. Also it minimizes layers of complexity compared to other solutions.

Here is an example using FFmpeg.

1. Check first for available Pulse sources

   ```
   $ pactl list short sources
   0    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_05.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
   1    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_05.0.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   ```
2. Use both as input for FFmpeg and pass them through a mix filter

   ```
   ffmpeg \
   -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_05.0.analog-stereo.monitor \
   -f pulse -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_05.0.analog-stereo \
   -filter_complex amix=inputs=2 recordedfile.mp3
   ```

   I used shell line break `\` for a clear code. otherwise it is a one-liner command. You may control volumes from Pulse control GUI.

Here reference with diagrams about FFmpeg mixer if you are not using stereo mic, flip to mono to minimize the file size.

- [StackOverflow: How to overlay/downmix two audio files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528482/724406)
- [FFmpeg: Manipulating audio channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation)

Jack and Pulse pipelines are best when it comes to Live mixer, Not just recording as in [Raffa's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1317187/26246) or [my answer for another use-case](https://askubuntu.com/a/421056/26246).