# Routing audio between headset and Behringer U-Control using pacmd

Tags: pulseaudio, pavucontrol

I've got a Behringer U-control USB device and I'm trying to learn pulseaudio / pacmd. The U-control has L/R input and L/R output (all RCA) plus digital, I don't need. I've worked out how to record from the inputs. I basically want to connect up the U-control to the laptop so that the laptop can send and receive audio.

How can I use pacmd to route the sound as follows:

(1) I'd like the L/R input of the U-control to be routed to my laptop speakers (or headphones), essentially monitoring the L/R input of the U-control.

(2) I'd like to route application/mic audio from the laptop to the L/R output of the U-control. I.e., I'd like to send sound from (A) one or more applications playing audio and/or (B) the mic from a headset.

How do I set up this routing using pacmd? (I've got pavucontrol, and can use that, though a fully self-contained solution in pacmd would be great.)

Thanks!

PS. I'm aware that Jack does some of this via a graphical interface. I've had a quick go at installing Jack on Ubuntu 20.04, but I didn't get very far. I also feels a little overkill for what I'd like to do - but if there's a simple guide to installing Jack and the kxstudio apps on Ubuntu 20.04, I'd be ok to try it - though worried about messing up my system.

PPS. Does anybody know if there's a graphical guide for translating a routing diagram into a set of pacmd commands?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1317187/968501

Comment: This is about a different problems, but it has some graphics: https://endless.ersoft.org/pulseaudio-loopback/