# Using the output from speakers as a virtual microphone input on the same device

Tags: sound, microphone, speakers

Not sure if title is clear enough. I want the output from the speakers to be treated as an input.

So I can play a video in one window and then the sound from the video will act as input

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1317187

Answer (score 3):

Totally do-able. The idea is you create a virtual speaker device, and have it connected to a virtual microphone device. On Windows, one could use a [virtual audio cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/). But on Ubuntu, that app doesn't exist. But we can still create a virtual audio cable using something like PulseAudio as described in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61990828/16886597). Here's the part of the post that answers your question:

> Create a virtual output device, and a virtual source from it's monitor.
>
> ```
> pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name="virtual_speaker" sink_properties=device.description="virtual_speaker"
> pactl load-module module-remap-source master="virtual_speaker.monitor" source_name="virtual_mic" source_properties=device.description="virtual_mic"
> ```
>
> Any sound played to "virtual_speaker" will be sent to "virtual_mic".
> (the rest of the linked answer is specific to doing it with FFmpeg)