# How to enable microphone loopback into headset

Tags: 22.04, microphone

I'm searching for a solution to hear myself (in Windows it's a simple checkbox). Any options? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic#262297) works very good for me on 20.04 (I don't have a 22.04 installation to test).

I copy the text below:

- Install PulseAudio Volume Control (`pavucontrol`):

  ```
   sudo apt install pavucontrol
  ```
- Now we will route your microphone to your speakers. Do this by running the following command:

  ```
   pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
  ```
- On the Recording tab of `pavucontrol`, you can show all streams (combobox at the bottom) and then configure which microphone (if you have more than one) should loopback into the built-in analog stereo
- To stop it running, run:

  ```
  pactl unload-module module-loopback
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply, play your microphone through your speakers like so:

```
aplay <(arecord -f cd)
```

More ways (*including recording*) can be found at [Recording phone calls in Ubuntu 20.04 - not just Skype](https://askubuntu.com/q/1316606)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [website](https://webcammictest.com/check-mic.html) in any Operating System to hear your own voice.

[image: webcammictest]

Select your input source on the top. Then set the **Delay** to "No", **Speaker**  to your output source (in this case your headset) and adjust the volume percentage in the **Volume** section. After this press **Start** to hear your own voice.