# How to hear microphone input on speakers

Tags: 22.04

I simply want to hear on my speakers my voice when speaking into my microphone, situated at some distance from my speakers to minimise feedback. I've tried all the suggested solutions at [How to hear my voice in speakers with a mic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [very similar question has been asked recently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490439/how-to-enable-microphone-loopback-into-headset/1491002), so I'll simply copy the answer:

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic#262297) works very good for me on 20.04 (I don't have a 22.04 installation to test).

I copy the text below:

- Install PulseAudio Volume Control (`pavucontrol`):

  ```
   sudo apt install pavucontrol
  ```
- Now we will route your microphone to your speakers. Do this by running the following command:

  ```
   pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
  ```
- On the Recording tab of `pavucontrol`, you can show all streams (combobox at the bottom) and then configure which microphone (if you have more than one) should loopback into the built-in analog stereo
- To stop it running, run:

  ```
  pactl unload-module module-loopback
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This works (in Terminal):

```
arecord -r 192000 -f s16_le --buffer-time=1 - | aplay -
```