# Recording output with Audacity

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, audio-recording, audacity

I'm trying to record my audio output in Audacity as explained for example in https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_linux.html.

At the step where I should select "pulse" I instead only see the options `pulse: Internal Mic` `pulse: Headphone Mic` `pulse: HeadSet Mic`. I've tried all of these but as somewhat expected they use the Mic rather than the audio output. I also tried setting the recording tab in "Pulse Audio Volume Control" to "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stero". This does not show all applications making sound by the way.

Any idea how to proceed in order to record my output?

Comment: Related: [Recording phone calls in Ubuntu 20.04 - not just Skype](https://askubuntu.com/q/1316606)