# Switch audio output from tray (headphone or speaker)

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, soundcard

Installed Ubuntu 18.10 and I'm very happy.

The only function i'm missing is **quick switching audio output profiles** of my soundcard.
In tray menu only ***volume control*** is possible, therefore I tried GNOME Shell Extension: ***Audio output selector,*** but it only switches between soundcards (internal speakers & USB soundcard) from the tray menu.

**I need to switch between the USB soundcard outputs (headphones & 3,5mm audio-out).** These are shown as Output profiles "***Speaker***" & "***Headphone***".

How can I enable a quick way to switch between these profiles? It's strange Ubuntu doesn't support any quick way to switch audio output from tray.
:(

[image: Audio output profile settings ubuntu]

thanks Pappl

Comment: may be you can use the same solution as described in similar question
https://askubuntu.com/a/970382/508895