# LXQt panel Volume Control doesn't switch to actual output device

Tags: lubuntu, 19.10, volume-control, lxqt

After switching audio output to a bluetooth speaker the Volume Control widget in the panel cannot be used. A manual setting is needed to select the new output in the widgets' configuration.

[image]

I could add a second instance of Volume control widget to the panel and try to use that only for bluetooth, but that looks a bit odd...

- Is there some way to make the LXQt panel Volume Control follow the actual audio output?
- Can I use a different volume control tool with that panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution is to use a different tool and remove completely that widget.

---

```
sudo apt install kmix
```

By default the actions on the tray icon don't affect the bluetooth speaker, until that speaker is selected as master channel (righ-click the icon, "Select Master Channel").

[image]

It shows no volume change pop-up on mouse actions on the tray icon (at least not in this LXQt).

---

```
sudo apt install qasmixer
```

Resize the window and drag it close to the volume icon.

[image: tray icon panel]

---

```
sudo apt install pasystray
```

It doesn't show a slider, nor a pop-up, and mouse actions are limited to scrolling volume up-sown (no mute), but it has other useful options like switching the audio output. More [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153248/925128).

Add `qasmixer -t` (start minimized in tray) and/or `kmix` & `pasystray`  to startup list.

---

Furthermore, if the bluetooth audio device volume cannot be controlled through the laptop keys, the following commands could be associated to the keys:

```
Toggle mute: `amixer -q -D pulse sset Master toggle`

Volume up by 5%: `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+`

Volume down by 5%: `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-`
```

Sources: [Terminal command to set audio volume?](https://askubuntu.com/a/97945/925128) and [How do you mute from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/444183/925128).