# Change audio output channel via short-cut

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, headphones

I have two audio output channels:

- internal speaker
- headset

I would like to switch between both via a key on the keyboard.

There are some special keys above the number block which I don't use. For example there is a key which opens a calculator.

How could I get this done?

Comment: creating a script that changes the output channel and then bind it to key press may work. This may help https://askubuntu.com/a/14083/1112104 or you can use some gnome-extensions like https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortcut to switch  between Analog Stereo output & HDMI audio output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41858/shortcut-to-switch-between-analog-stereo-output-hdmi-audio-output)

Answer (score 1):

I created a script which changes the audio-sink in a round-robin fashion:

https://github.com/guettli/change-audio-sink/blob/main/change-audio-sink.py

You can map this script to a key with your desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

[As said](https://askubuntu.com/a/898638/349837), on *Settings → Keyboard shortcuts* you can create a custom one to a command similar to:

```
bash -c '[[ $(pacmd list-cards | grep "active profile" | cut -d " " -f 3-) = "<output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo>" ]] && pacmd set-card-profile 0 "output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo" || pacmd set-card-profile 0 "output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo"'
```

Of course you should change the card profiles accordingly of those between you want to toggle.

[image: screenshot]

[See also](https://askubuntu.com/q/970323/349837).